# "Failed to set field" Problem with SimpleTest, testing a form

Tags: 7, testing

With SimpleTests, I want to test a form similar to :

```
  // Textfield :
  $form['fieldset_name']['test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    ...
  );
  // Submit :
  $form['fieldset_name']['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#submit' => array('my_module_form_submit'),
    '#value' => 'Submit button',
  );
```

This form is accessed from 'admin/config/my_module'. So I add the following test in my_module.test :

```
  function testForm() {
    $path = 'admin/config/my_module';
    $edit['test'] = 'testing field\'s input';
    $this->drupalPost($path, $edit, t('Submit button'));
  }
```

When I run the test, it fails with these errors :

> Failed to set field test to testing field\'s input
>
> Found the Add button (failed)

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: $edit has to be keyed with field name. Did you check if "test" is the field name for which you are trying to set the value?

Comment: I know that, the problem was related to my configuration setting $this->setup =TRUE, I switched back to normal testing environment tables and it went OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions would be my first guess.

Enable debug output in the Simpletest settings and then check if your module is installed and you have permissions to visit that page.

Comment: I used drupalLogin and loaded a user with 'access administration pages', the account is used (its tests pass) but the form's test output same errors. The module is enable and and I used $this->setup = TRUE : is it the problem ?.

Comment: access administration pages has no magic meaning, it's just a permission as any other, you need to specify the exact permission required by your module. As I said, enable debugging, it should write each requested page into a file and add a link to it so that you can see what the test sees. No idea if it's because of the overriden setUp(), could be, debug output might tell you that. I've commented on your question why I find it a bad idea in general ;)

Comment: There is some progress from greggory.hz's question I used profile = testing and a proper environment, now the test seems to work. About debug output, do you mean verbose ? because I see no debug option in settings.

Comment: Yes, that's the setting I meant.